# Setup and Deployement in VB.Net having Sql Server Database in the Project

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, clickonce, setup-deployment

I have completed my Project in VB.Net and has published my project.
But i want to come out of these things

1. I have Sql Server Database in my project and i want my setup to add that database to sql server on installing my project.
2. I want my application to automatically detect sql server 2008 r2 and if it is not instaled i want it to install for me and then atach the database.
3. I dont want to add the database as a Attached database in my project.
4. i dont want to install crystal report in my application.
5. I have some unused refernces in my application in my project which i want to removed, i have tried the default visual studio remove unused references but still have some references like shockwave.dll log2net.dll etc.

Comment: i had worked on these and googled but didn't find any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be to switch to an MSI-based installer. This should allow you to resolve issues **3** and **5** (you control what the MSI includes). You can use a [Visual Studio setup project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353), [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or a [commercial setup authoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software).

For installing your database (issue **1**), the best approach depends on how you use your database. Some installers simply copy the database files, others install it using [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) and others execute SQL scripts. You should first determine how you want to install it and then ask a more specific question if you encounter problems.

To install SQL Server when it's not found (issue **2**), you can use a prerequisite. This is done differently for each setup tool, so you first need to decide on a tool and then research how it supports prerequisites.

For issue **4**, I'm not sure I know what to say. An MSI package will install what you include in it. If you don't add Crystal Reports in your package, then it won't be installed.

Answer (score -1):

Visit
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10032/Deploy-SQL-Server-databases-easily-with-an-Install

Deploy SQL Server databases easily with an Installer class

Best regards!
Elias Sant Anna